# FancyTree persist and cookies

Tags: javascript, grails, cookies, groovy, fancytree

I'm using fancyTree with persist extension in Groovy and Grails  mode. I am uploading the data to the tree through AJAX (json). Anytime I click on the leaf another path opens on the same domain but different path. For every path another cookie is created. Is it possible to create only one root cookie rather than one for every path that the three is redirected?

anytime the new path is loaded so is the fancyTree is reloaded. Having one cookie would keep the tree consistent throughout.